# Amazon Gamecircle Friends

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I have integrated Amazon Game Circle api in my kindle application. I have managed to obtain the Friends and Learder board feature successfully. Now i want to obtain my game circle friends ? Is such a thing possible ?

In IOS we get can get our game center friends, is such a thing possible in the Amazon Game Circle ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Not yet.  As of v2.3, GameCircle doesn't expose any API for retrieving GameCircle friends.

https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/engage/gamecircle/javadoc